# Matplotlib set fixed y axis values and rename them

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to put these fixed values in the Y axis (They need to always appear on the graph, even if they aren't in the values list) in order (bad/3.33, ok/6.66, good/9.99), rename each to the following:

```
3.33 = bad
6.66 = ok
9.99 = good

`fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(16, 6), frameon = False)
names = ['Assiduidade', 'limpeza/organizacao', 'Carro', 'Ferramentas', 'Iclass', "EPI's", 'Organização da base']
values = [3.33, 3.33, 6.66, 3.33, 9.99, 9.99, 9.99]
axs.bar(names, values)
fig.suptitle(Title)
plt.show()`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?

```
axs.set_yticks([3.33, 6.66, 9.99])
axs.set_yticklabels(["bad","ok","good"])
```

[image]

Comment: It worked (I'm also very grateful), but the y axys values just appear if they're in the values list. If there's a way to make them fixed values in the Y axys, it will solve everything.

Comment: You could just fix the leak limits of the axes `axs.set_ylim(0,10)` or something like that to make sure all the ticks are always shown